# How to read command line parameter in InstallShield script

Tags: installshield

Suppose I run my installer like this:

```
setup.exe /v"PARAMETER=Value"
```

How can I read `PARAMETER`? The documentation proposes to use `GetProfString` and `GetProfInt`, but which folder should I use?

Answer (score 0):

For me the folders for `setup.ini` were I thought parameters would go are as follows:

- ENGINECOMMONDIR
- ENGINEDIR

  ```
  C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
  ```
- SRCDIR

  ```
  C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\Disk1
  ```

But instead one needs to use system string variable [CMDLINE](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefCMDLINE.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to [`CMDLINE`](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield25helplib/installshield25helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefCMDLINE.htm?Highlight=CMDLINE) suggests you are using an InstallScript or InstallScript MSI project, which is populated through the `/z` notation to its setup.exe.

The `/v"PARAMETER=Value"` [notation](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield25helplib/installshield25helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm?Highlight=setup%20command-line) applies to the setup.exe used for Windows Installer projects, passing `PARAMETER=Value` to Windows Installer, which in turns sets the Windows Installer property `PARAMETER` to `Value`. The way to read it depends on the context in which you need it, but typically involves either a formatted text field including a reference to the property (e.g. `[PARAMETER]`), or code that retrieves a property through e.g. `MsiGetProperty(hInstall, L"PARAMETER", buf, bufsize)` (C++) or `Session.Property("PARAMETER")` (VB).