# Impossible to escape blank space?

Tags: command-line, escaping, installshield

I am really desperate.
I'm working under InstallShield to create an installer.
At one point, I have to run an .exe file but specify the destination folder for the installation. Problem the destination path contains blanks space and despite all the solutions I found, nothing works...

I tried to do something like this:

```
MySetup.exe /V"INSTALLDIR="c:\program files\Install\My Folder";
```

It doesn't work. I replaced "program files" with "PROGA~1", it works. If I don't put the "My Folder" part (but I must have this part and I can't put another folder).
I tried to put between double quote for example:

```
MySetup.exe /V"INSTALLDIR=c:\PROGRA~1\Install\"My Setup""
```

Each time, either I get an error message telling me that the command line is incorrect, or I get a command line explanation window that opens (but nothing is executed)...

Am I in a case where my installer doesn't accept to have a space in the folder name and that makes it totally impossible to execute it?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error complaining about an invalid command line or the installation fails complaining the install folder is not valid?

Here is a more details about the command line params from an InstallShield employee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255072/how-to-read-command-line-parameter-in-installshield-script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MySetup.exe /V"INSTALLDIR="\c:\program files\Install\My Folder"/qn";
```

or:

```
MySetup.exe /S /V"INSTALLDIR="\c:\program files\Install\My Folder"/qn";
```